# Hide TabBar when clicked on one tab Item

Tags: iphone

I have four `tabBarItem`s.  When a user clicks on the first tab item the tab bar should be hidden.  The other three tab bars should appear.  Is this possible?

Comment: Make your custom tab bar control. Apple does not provide such facility to developer that you have.

Comment: @RRB- hidden property wont work in this case ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning up front: this is an unusual handling of tab bars.

If you hook up the UITabBarItem as an IBOutlet, and also hook up the UITabBarController's delegate, then in the method  tabBarController:didSelectViewController:  you can test to see if the user has tapped the tab bar you're interested in.  If so, you can set it's title property to @"" and if it has an image you can set it's image property to nil.

This will look sort of strange though - it will give you a fully functioning tabBarItem, that is basically transparent.

If you really want the tabBarItem to disappear, remove it from the tabBarController, by resetting the tabBarControllers.viewControllers property to an array that does NOT contain the viewController you want to hide.