# How to hide Tabbar in UITabbar Controller first 3 view Controller in ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am using `UITabbarController` in main xib. Then in tabview controller for first item I'm using navigation controller. There I want to hide tabview on this navigation controller like as first 3 view controller I want to hide  tabview and from 4th  view controller I want tabview on view controller. So how I can do this?

Comment: please elaborate your question.. i cant get you.

Comment: ya sure first I open main xib then select UITabViewController there two ViewController already then then on first View Controller I applied UINavigation Controller then I want to hide TabView on this View controller same thing goes in second and third ViewController and after this 4th and next View Controller I want again UITabView on 4th and next View Controllers .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072425/hide-tabbar-when-clicked-on-one-tab-item

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383069/how-to-hide-show-tab-bar-of-a-view-with-a-navigation-bar-in-ios/9141766#9141766

Comment: @iPatel : flag the question as duplicate